# How to get Hive Application Id using Hive JDBC connection

Tags: java, jdbc, hive

Here is how I am running queries through hive JDBC

```
Class.forName(DRIVER);
Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

Response = Connection.createStatement();
ResultSet = Response.executeQuery(query);
```

From YARN URL, Unable to find application id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Class.forName(DRIVER);
Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

HiveStatement stmt = (HiveStatement) Connection.createStatement();

ResultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);

for(String log: stmt.getQueryLog()) {

      System.out.println("Log: "+log)
}
```